# python SPARQLWrapper return only 10000 results

Tags: python, python-3.x, sparql, virtuoso, sparqlwrapper

I use the SPARQLWrapper module to launch a query to a virtuoso endpoint and get the result.

The query always return a maximum of 10000 results

Here is the python script:

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON 

queryString = """ 
SELECT DISTINCT ?s
WHERE {
    ?s ?p ?o .
}
"""


sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://localhost:8890/sparql")
sparql.setQuery(queryString)
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)

res = sparql.query().convert()

# Parse result
parsed = []
for entry in res['results']['bindings']:
    for sparql_variable in entry.keys():
        parsed.append({sparql_variable: entry[sparql_variable]['value']})

print('Query return ' + str(len(parsed)) + ' results')
```

When I lauch the query with

```
SELECT count(*) AS ?count
```

I get the right number of triples : 917051.

Why the SPARQLWrapper module limit the number of result to 10000 ?

How do I get all the results ?

Comment: What do you mean by "launch directly"? Usually Virtuoso has a default limit set in the `virtuoso.ini` file - so at first, you should check your configuration.

Comment: when a launch the query with a count into the conductor interface of virtuoso, I get the right number. I change the parameters in the .ini file and it worked, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to adjust the [Virtuoso configuration file, as documented](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtConfigScale).  Specifically for this case, you need to increase the `ResultSetMaxRows` in the `[SPARQL]` stanza.

The limit is not in SPARQLWrapper.  You would see the same limit if you did the full `SELECT` (instead of the `COUNT`, which only delivers 1 row) through the SPARQL endpoint, Conductor, or any other interface.

Answer (score 0):

The 10000 results is set by the data owner via the item `ResultSetMaxRows` in the `virtuoso.ini`, to protect the data.
If not, anyone can use a simple sparql query `select * where {?s ?p ?o}` to get all the data which may cost the data owner a lot of time and money.